# Lightbox does not overlay the page

Tags: overlay, lightbox

Lightbox does not overlay the page, instead it enlarges the page and adds the image at the bottom, way below the normal page end, how do I resolve. I tried installing the latest version of Lightbox but has not resolved. Inspecting the page in the browser shows lightboxOverlay height 7681px which is or course the extra length of the page.

Installed latest Lightbox but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by changing the CSS link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

The type is probably not needed but as it is it works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).